# Trying to save an image in VS C# exits with code -2147483645 (0x80000003)

Tags: c#

so I'm trying to save an image via this code:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialogThing = new SaveFileDialog();
Bitmap test = new Bitmap(5, 5);
//Do some image edit thingies
  try
  {
    if(saveFileDialogThing.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
    test.Save(saveFileDialogThing.FileName);
    }
  }
catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
```

When running in Debug configuration, everything works as intended. However, when running in Release configuration, it doesn't save the file and instead crashes with
`The program '[19656] Cool Program.exe' has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).`, without even catching whatever exception may be causing this, if any. What gives?

This also happens when trying to open an image like so:

```
Bitmap imgIn;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialogTest = new OpenFileDialog();

openFileDialogTest.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
openFileDialogTest.Filter = "Image files (*.png)|*.png";
openFileDialogTest.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialogTest.RestoreDirectory = true;
  if (openFileDialogTest.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    filePath = openFileDialogTest.FileName;
    imgIn = new Bitmap(filePath);
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards,

radzo73

Comment: Hello. In the first snippet,  there is this different variable names saveFileDialogThing /saveFileDialogTest are these the same or is there another variable named saveFileDialogTest ?

Comment: Anyhow I replaced saveFileDialogTest  with saveFileDialogThing . I put string before filepath etc. I created a windows form application with this code. I didn't get any error with release exe.  Coıuld you give more details regarding your code/project ?

Comment: @AntiqTech yeah, the `saveFileDialogTest` in the first example was a typo, sorry. The project is written in C# 7.3 (thanks autoselect based on framework version, very helpful), and that's really all I know. I might try just porting all the code to a new project and see what happens

Comment: and hey, creating a new project (.net 4.7.2, C# 7.3, just like the other project) and using the exact same code works as intended with the release exe. What gives?

Comment: 0x80000003 is the breakpoint exception.  Which suggests that the code still contains a Debugger.Break() statement.  If you can't find it then it could be present in a misbehaving shell extension, SysInternals' AutoRuns can disable it.

Comment: That's weird. as @Hans suggested, it might be due to breakpoint information for the debugger. Clear any breakpoints, clear and rebuild your project and the give it a try.